# SQLAlchemy multiple foreign keys in one mapped class to the same primary key

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Am trying to setup a postgresql table that has two foreign keys that point to the same primary key in another table.

When I run the script I get the error

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Company.stakeholder - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

That is the exact error in the [SQLAlchemy Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths) yet when I replicate what they have offered as a solution the error doesn't go away. What could I be doing wrong?

```
#The business case here is that a company can be a stakeholder in another company.
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)

class Stakeholder(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stakeholder'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False)
    stakeholder_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False)
    company = relationship("Company", foreign_keys='company_id')
    stakeholder = relationship("Company", foreign_keys='stakeholder_id')
```

I have seen similar questions here but [some of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9222924/1082673) recommend one uses a `primaryjoin` yet in the documentation it states that you don't need the `primaryjoin` in this situation.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Tried removing quotes from the foreign_keys and making them a list. From official documentation on [`Relationship Configuration: Handling Multiple Join Paths`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths)

> Changed in version 0.8: `relationship()` can resolve ambiguity between
>   foreign key targets on the basis of the `foreign_keys` argument alone;
>   the `primaryjoin` argument is no longer needed in this situation.

---

Self-contained code below works with `sqlalchemy>=0.9`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine(u'sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()

#The business case here is that a company can be a stakeholder in another company.
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)

class Stakeholder(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stakeholder'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False)
    stakeholder_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False)
    company = relationship("Company", foreign_keys=[company_id])
    stakeholder = relationship("Company", foreign_keys=[stakeholder_id])

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# simple query test
q1 = session.query(Company).all()
q2 = session.query(Stakeholder).all()
```

Comment: After doing that, am getting the error `sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'company' and 'stakeholder'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.`

Comment: what version of sqlalchemy do you have?

Comment: Got `SQLAlchemy==0.9.1`

Comment: Ok. This has worked. Question though, would it make sense to put a backref on the Company table like this `stakeholder = relationship("Stakeholder", backref="company")`? or that would be redundant?

Comment: It depends if you need it or not. Do you need to navigate from `Stakeholder` to the `Company`? In any case be careful because you cannot put the same name for `backref` for both relationships, so in case you do, i would put something like `company = relationship("Company", foreign_keys=[company_id], backref="holders")` and `stakeholder = relationship("Company", foreign_keys=[stakeholder_id], backref="holdings")`.

Comment: Another question: if your `Stakeholder` table does not contain anything else (like percentage owned, since when etc), but pure relationship information, why don't you use pure [Many-to-Many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many) relationship setup?

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. As for the stakeholder table, it does contain other attributes so the many to many relationship wouldn't do for now

Comment: How to use this with mixins?

Comment: `NameError: name 'thing_id' is not defined.`  With latest sqla stable.  :-(

Comment: Why sqlalchemy use foreign_keys argument as a list if we always pass only one element list? is there some situation when we use foreign keys as two-element list?

Comment: Backref  was discussed but what about 'back_populates'?

Comment: Here is a more clear explanation if the above answer does not work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44434708/7335848

Comment: @MatijaLukic you can create composite foreign key, so this is when you'd put multiple columns inside this list.

Answer (score 11):

The latest documentation:

- http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths

The form of `foreign_keys=` in the documentation produces a NameError, not sure how it is expected to work when the class hasn't been created yet.  With some hacking I was able to succeed with this:

```
company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False)
company = relationship("Company", foreign_keys='Stakeholder.company_id')

stakeholder_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False)
stakeholder = relationship("Company",
                            foreign_keys='Stakeholder.stakeholder_id')
```

In other words:

```
… foreign_keys='CurrentClass.thing_id')
```

Comment: The documentation has been updated, there's no typo. The approach from the documentation will work even before the class is created

Comment: See the accepted answer.  just give `foreign_keys=[stakeholder_id]`