# SQLAlchemy - Multiple Foreign key pointing to same table same attribute

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, entity-relationship

My data base structure....

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    user = db.relationship("BankSlip", back_populates="person_user")
    reference = db.relationship("BankSlip", back_populates="person_reference")

class BankSlip(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    person_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Person.id))
    person_ref_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Person.id))

    person_user = db.relationship("Person", back_populates="user", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[person_user_id])
    person_reference = db.relationship("Person", back_populates="reference", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[person_ref_id])
```

I get the following errors while running at sqlite with Flask-SQLAlchemy

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Person.user - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

Here is my `pip freeze`

```
appdirs==1.4.3
APScheduler==3.3.1
bcrypt==3.1.3
blinker==1.4
cffi==1.9.1
click==6.7
cssselect==1.0.1
cssutils==1.0.2
Flask==0.12
Flask-Login==0.4.0
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.5
lxml==3.7.3
MarkupSafe==1.0
nose==1.3.7
packaging==16.8
pkg-resources==0.0.0
premailer==3.0.1
pycparser==2.17
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.13.0
schedule==0.4.2
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.6
tzlocal==1.4
uWSGI==2.0.15
Werkzeug==0.12.1
WTForms==2.1
```

**Edit**: One BankSlip can have one user and one reference.... It should be a one-to-one relationship where `parent -> child` is `BankSlip -> User` or `BankSlip -> Reference`. So, a child can have multiple parents!

Comment: That still does not require `uselist=False` BankSlip side. `person_user` and `person_reference` are still one to many relationships separately, where many BankSlips can relate to one Person. If you want one to one, define `uselist=False` at Person's side. Is that meant to be so that a BankSlip can have a user relationship, or reference relationship, but not both?

Comment: Sorry, mixed the order, the relationships in BankSlip are many to one, the ones in Person one to many. Still, uselist to Person's relationships.

Comment: Thank you very much! I mixed up 121 with 12n. uselist should be True or default....

Comment: Also, do you think that it's wrong example? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one

Comment: No, note that in the latter example the relationship is many to one, i.e. a child could have multiple parents (the foreign key is in the parent), so that's why the argument is on the child's relationship to make it one to one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Provide the required foreign_keys argument, as instructed by the error message:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    user = db.relationship("BankSlip", foreign_keys='BankSlip.person_user_id', back_populates="person_user")
    reference = db.relationship("BankSlip", foreign_keys='BankSlip.person_ref_id', back_populates="person_reference")
```

With Declarative [you can define the foreign keys as a string](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html), which will help in resolving the circular dependency. Alternatively you could use backref instead of back_populates:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class BankSlip(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    person_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Person.id))
    person_ref_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Person.id))

    person_user = db.relationship("Person", backref="user", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[person_user_id])
    person_reference = db.relationship("Person", backref="reference", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[person_ref_id])
```

Note that you've got the `uselist=False` at the wrong end of the relationship, or it is redundant, since a Person can be referenced by multiple BankSlips. It belongs at Persons's side, so:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref

...
    person_user = db.relationship("Person", backref=backref("user", uselist=False), foreign_keys=[person_user_id])
    person_reference = db.relationship("Person", backref=backref("reference", uselist=False), foreign_keys=[person_ref_id])
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. Docs lack of examples, and without them you cannot understand a lot of their complicated concepts. Like this concept, it's horrible, but that's SQL Alchemy, there is no better ORM.

Comment: my learning from debugging one of these cases: the foreign_keys parameter is like a helper parameter that you can toss in there when sqlalchemy can't figure things out.  That's in contrast to following the sqla docs verbatim and then being stuck.