# Sqlalchemy Multiple Foreign Keys in secondary table

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I started off with this setup:

```
checklist_participants = Table('checklist_participants', base.metadata,
                               Column('checklist_id', Integer, ForeignKey('checklists.id', ondelete='cascade')),
                               Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='cascade'))
                               )

class Checklist(base):
    __tablename__ = 'checklists'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    participants = relationship('User', secondary='checklist_participants', back_populates='joined_checklists')

class User(base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    joined_checklists = relationship('Checklist', secondary='checklist_participants', back_populates='participants')
```

In order to give an extra column `referring_user` to the secondary table `checklist_participants`, I moved it into its own class like so:

```
# new class
class Participant(base):
    checklist_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('checklists.id', ondelete='cascade'), primary_key=True)
    checklist = relationship('Checklist', foreign_keys=checklist_id)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='cascade'), primary_key=True)
    user = relationship('User', foreign_keys=user_id)
    # new column
    referring_user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='set null'))
    referring_user = relationship('User', foreign_keys=referring_user_id)

class User(base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    joined_checklists = relationship('Checklist', secondary='checklist_participants', back_populates='participants')
    # new relationship definition
    referred_participants = relationship('Participant', back_populates='referring_user')
```

Simply moving the join table into its own class didn't cause any problems. But when I introduced the new column and tried to run a simple query:
`session.query(User).filter(User.id == input_id).scalar()`
I got this error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Checklist.participants - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table 'checklist_participants'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child tables.`

What do I need to define on my models to fix this issue?

Comment: Please include your relationship definitions in `User` and `Participant` after adopting the association object pattern. Long story short, you need to explicitly tell the relationships between `User` and `Participant` which foreign key columns to use, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355890/sqlalchemy-multiple-foreign-keys-in-one-mapped-class-to-the-same-primary-key. In the query you've shown you have no joins, so the error seems like it's caused by the relationships.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I added relationship definitions, but got a new error about the `foreign_keys` argument. I edited the main post to show my changes and the new error. I don't understand why the error is related to `Checklist.participants`... My `Participant` table just has a single foreign key to `Checklist`, so there should be no confusion over the key to choose.

Comment: If `Checklist.participants` is still a relationship to `User`, then there are multiple paths from checklist to user after the addition of the 2nd foreign key.

Comment: I see. So I would have to tell the `Checklist.participants` relationship which foreign_key on the secondary table has to be used to connect to `User`? If I try to add `foreign_keys='Participant.user_id'` to that `Checklist.participants` relationship, I get another new exception: `sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Checklist.participants - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'checklist_participants'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @IljaEverilä, I realized why the relationships were ambiguous. I couldn't figure out, how to tell `Checklist.participants` which foreign key on the join table was the one to use. Instead, I removed the `secondary` argument from my relationships and made `Checklist` and `User` relationships connect to `Participant` instead of referencing each other directly. That way, `Checklist` didn't need to know about the foreign keys used in `Participant`.
However, these changes moved the problem into the `User` class, where I was now referencing `Participant` twice. This time, I was able to define the `foreign_keys` argument on these two ManyToOne relationships to fix the ambiguity:

```
class User(base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    participants = relationship('Participant', back_populates='user', foreign_keys='Participant.user_id')
    referred_participants = relationship('Participant', back_populates='referring_user', foreign_keys='Participant.referring_user_id')


class Checklist(base):
    __tablename__ = 'checklists'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    participants = relationship('Participant', back_populates='checklist')

class Participant(base):
    __tablename__ = 'checklist_participants'

    checklist_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('checklists.id', ondelete='cascade'), primary_key=True)
    checklist = relationship('Checklist', foreign_keys=checklist_id)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='cascade'), primary_key=True)
    user = relationship('User', foreign_keys=user_id)
    referring_user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='set null'))
    referring_user = relationship('User', foreign_keys=referring_user_id)
```

Comment: Great but this is not the answer to the question as now people with Multiple Foreign Keys in secondary table error get redirected here and you suggest removing secondary table

Comment: Agree, still - got me looking and Your comment, @Superpassteque, gave me a hint to look further, and I think I found some here on the subject: https://realpython.com/python-sqlite-sqlalchemy/ - indeed - reading that page and copying the concept made my warnings go away.

Answer (score 0):

Declarative version, worked for me:

```
 class Offer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "offers"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=True)
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates= "offers", foreign_keys=[user_id])

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    offers: Mapped[List["Offer"]] = relationship(back_populates= "user", foreign_keys=[Offer.user_id])
```